# How do I cancel a Visual Studio Online build based on a variable set in the TaskContext?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Task 1 is a PowerShell script. It sets a variable `##vso[task.setvariable variable=Metadata.ContinueGen;]false`

Task 2 has a custom condition where it will only run if the `eq(variables['Metadata.ContinueGen'], true)` condition is met. The task is skipped, which is okay. But I still have an entire series of tasks that I'd like to not run.

I'd like to figure out how to stop the remaining build tasks without having to apply the condition to each task definition.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you would like to stop the build if a condition takes place..

If you put this in your powershell script, it will error and quit the rest of your activities.

```
Write-Error ("Stopping Build steps, will not continue to the next")
exit 1
```

Comment: That would work although I'd still like the build to complete with some sort of success+cancelled status instead of error.

Comment: The only drawback is that it shows a failed build in dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Custom conditions only can set **how to run the task not all the following tasks**. So you need to set custom conditions for all the following tasks (if you want to archived by custom conditions).

But there is **another way you can skip/cancel the following tasks** if the variable `Metadata.ContinueGen` is `false`. Detail steps as below:

1. Set all the following tasks with default condition **Only when all previous tasks have succeeded**.
2. Before the tasks add a **PowerShell task** to compare if the value for `Metadata.ContinueGen` is false. If it’s false, then set jobstatus as canceled：

   ```
   Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=agent.jobstatus;]canceled"
   ```
3. If the `Metadata.ContinueGen` is false, the following tasks will also canceled since the status for the PowerShell task is not succeeded.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/2163 seems to provide an easier version, by calling two `Write-Host`.

Answer (score 1):

（The other answers are also valid, but they trigger failed/succeeded to be logged in dashboard.)

I created a PowerShell script called `vstsabort`, so that during the build you can call it to cancel the whole build if you like.

https://github.com/lextm/vstsabort

1. Generate a Personal Access Token and make sure it has "Build (read and execute)" scope selected.
2. Add this token to your pipeline under Variables section as a new variable (for example system.pat). Make sure you click "Change variable type to secret" to lock down the value.
3. Add a verification task in your pipeline (Batch Script as example). Make sure "$(system.pat)" is passed as Arguments.
4. In the actual batch file (prepare.abort.bat in my case), call the utility,

The batch file might look like,

```
echo no change. abort.
set LEXTUDIO_VSTSABORT=TRUE
set SYSTEM_PAT=%~1
powershell -executionpolicy bypass -File abort.ps1
```

Then in dashboard you can see this build is cancelled.